# Make the function in this code run a different greeting based upon the value of each customer's 'visits'

Tags: javascript, parameters

I am trying to make the function in this code run a different greeting based upon the value of each customer's 'visits'.  I keep getting an error that says "Cannot read property 'visits' of undefined."

What am I missing here?

```html
var customerData = {
  'Joe': {
    visits: 1
  },
  'Carol': {
    visits: 2
  },
  'Howard': {
    visits: 3,
  },
  'Carrie': {
    visits: 4
  }
};


function greetCustomer(firstName) {
  var greeting = '';
  
  if(customerData.firstName.visits === 1){
        greeting = "Welcome back, " + firstname +"!" + " We're glad you liked us the first time!";
  }
  else if(customerData.firstName.visits > 1){
        greeting = "Welcome back, " + firstname +"!" + " So glad to see you again!";
  }
  else{
      greeting = "Welcome! Is this your first time?";
  }
  
  return greeting;
}

greetCustomer("Carrie");
```

Comment: There is no literal property `firstName`. Instead, use bracket notation: `customerData[firstName].visits`

Comment: Doesn't seem to fix it

Comment: Why not? What doesn't work?

Comment: I changed the if statement to:

if(customerData[firstName].visits === 1){
..............

Is this what you meant?

Comment: yes, with bracket notation

Comment: It give me the error "ReferenceError: firstname is not defined"

Comment: forgot to capitalize, now it works, thanks so much!